# The correct way to define a ROI

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, roi, template-matching

I'm currently working on a image processing project opencv python based, and essentially it's quite simple, it uses cv2.matchTemplate and a database to make all the matches, but I think something is done wrong.

The images are get from a few cameras, then the processing starts, based on predefined masks, the ROI of each object is returned the ROI of to then be matched with a database of images.

The problem is, the database has crops are the same size of the ROI predefined, which means the cv2.matchTemplate is always trying to match an image of the same size as the one in the database.

Here's an example with a printed circuit board (which is what my project does, it looks for bad positioned components/missing components).

[Simple circuit board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71j6d.jpg)

This would be the full raw image, taken from one of the cameras.

Next a predefined filter would be applied to the raw image, I usually convert it to grayscale.

Now, my predefined ROI would crop the image.

[Image ROI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fn68A.jpg)

[Image crop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVZBT.jpg)

Notice though it crops way more than the component itself, and this crop will be saved in the database for eventual matches.

But shouldn't I be manually feeding my database with properly images? I mean, is it ideal? wouldn't it take way more matches (images) to get my desired threshold?

I need arguments to convince someone of it, I want to feed my database with well cropped images, but this person just wants to save it automatically.

Thanks!

Comment: just do both and see who's right? chances are, they will get somewhat worse results from badly labeled (cropped) data. -- also... this isn't a programming question but about methods. best ask this on the AI/ML stack exchanges.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this really is a method question, but I didnt know any other reliable place to ask this kinda of question.